# ZRTP and OtR on Windows Surface

Tags: xmpp

Any advice on using ZRTP and OtR over XMPP on a Window Surface tablet device?  Would Jitsi work?  Miranda IM has surface versions and an [open source OtR plugin](https://code.google.com/p/mirotr/) supposedly.

Comment: Apologies for such a basic question, but I've minimal access to the device, and almost zero familiarity with any Microsoft platforms.

Comment: I'm merely looking for XMPP and SIP clients with usable implementations for OtR and ZRTP, respectively.  Just don't have enough access to the platform to see if things like MirOtR run on ARM.  And not so much info available.